# Are All Price Values in catalog_product_entity_decimal?

Tags: magento

Are all the prices in the **value** column of `catalog_product_entity_decimal` mysql table ?
I need to mass update the prices (converting from USD to GBP since Im switching the base currency to GBP)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are.  Even if you only put in an integer in the price field for a product, it converts it to decimal, as the price attribute itself is a decimal value.

Answer (score 0):

Tiered product prices, if you use them, are found in the sensibly named "catalog_product_entity_tier_price" table. The structure of this table is different to that of the other entity tables.